# Parameters estimation by MLE and Kalman filter

Tags: maximum-likelihood, kalman-filter, state-space-models

I am trying to estimate the parameters of a discrete nonlinear state space model using MLE and kalman filter:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x_k & = f(x_{k-1},\theta)+q_{k-1}\\
y_k & = h(x_k,\theta)+r_k
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}

And $x_k$ the state of the dynamic system at discrete time $k$, $y_k$ is the measurement, $q_{k-1}$ and $r_k$ are independent process and measurement Gaussian noise sequences with zeros means and covariances $Q_k$ and$R_k$ respectively.

one of the parameters actually is the product of two parameters ($\theta_1 = a_mk_m$ = 1), I have the value of $\theta_2 = k_m = 2$ (hence $a_m = 0.5$) reported in the literature.

I tried to estimate each one separately using synthetic data generated based on the values of parameters reported in the literature, the parameters estimates that I obtain are: $\hat{a}_m = 0.456$ and $\hat{k}_m = 2.223$ But the product  $\hat{\theta_1} = \hat{a}_m\hat{k}_m = 1.013$.

Now, I am trying to estimate directly the value of $\theta_1 = a_mk_m$, at some point I need to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$ of the evolution function, $f$ is a vector valued function and:
$$f_1 = a_mk_m(x_1-1) + 2k_m x_2 + k_m^2 (x_3-1) $$

So, the derivative of $\frac{\partial f1}{\partial k_m} = a_m(x_1-1) + 2x_2 + 2k_m(x_3-1)$, but here $a_m$ is not defined as separate parameter.

The question here can I replace $a_m$ by $1/k_m$. If the response is no, is there any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean that it is known(assumed) that $a_m\,k_m=1$? In that case, seems rather obvious that this equivalently means $a_m=1/k_m$?  If that is not meant, this is unclear. Also, does the subscript $m$ mean something?